# I can't run " npm-install" in terminal

Tags: npm-install

npm ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! network Socket timeout
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

I need to fix this problem, Thanks for feedback

Comment: Well, are you connected to a VPN or some other proxy? If yes, you have to configure the proxy in your npm config.